# In Java , Can't access protected members of super-class from sub-class

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Super {
   protected int a;
   protected Super(int a) { this.a = a; }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub(int a) { super(a); }
    public Sub() { this.a = 5; }
}




  public Sub() { this.a = 5; }
```

this.a=5 doesn't work. Why is this so? Protected and public members should be inherited.

Comment: It seems that your `Super` class have only constructor with parameter. So you have either to create constructor without parameters in class `Super`, either to call constructor of `Super` with super(0) and then perform your assignment.

Comment: I got that. But what is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Now if only the compiler would give you some kind of message describing the error it has found, that would save you from having to guess what happened… OH WAIT. IT DOES. Please read the error message in the future.

Comment: I got the message, that the constructor was missing. I never called super(). So why should that be a problem?

Comment: If your base class doesn't provide constructor without parameters then JVM doesn't know how to create instance of the class. So you have to call it explicitly in your subclass. See JLS for details, paragraph 8.8.9 (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.9 )

Comment: Also, take a look at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem isn't that you access the variable, but that you don't call the base constructor:

```
class Super {
   protected int a;
   protected Super(int a) { this.a = a; }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub(int a) { super(a); }
    public Sub() { 
       super(0);  // <-- call base constructor
       this.a = 5; 
    }
}
```

This happens because you didn't define a default constructor for `Super`, so derived classes don't know which constructor to call if you're not specifying one.

Comment: @JBNizet obviously, but I was trying to illustrate that you can modify the protected member directly in the derived class.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore we answered at the same time. I think I have to remove my comment.

Comment: @uthark I saw your comment right after I posted the answer. Why was it a comment btw?

Comment: I thought that the question is so simple, that comment will be enough.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Your parameterless constructor in `Sub` is attempting to implicitly invoke a parameterless constructor in `Super` which doesn't exist, which is (I assume) why you're getting a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

What does not work? Works for me...

What you do not have is a default constructor - in `public Sub() {this.a = 5; }` the parent default constructor is called, which you have not provided. If I compiler your code I get:

```
cannot find symbol constructor Super()
```

So you either have to have a default constructor or do: `public Sub() { super(5); }`

Comment: Why is the Super() called implicitly?

Comment: By language design - enforces that all supers are initialised for a new instance. So if you omit a call to a superclass constructor, the compiler will add the default one for you.